# Update database column if other specific column matches variable

Tags: python, django

I'm in process of creating a script for my django server that updates a database column named `TaskStatus` if data from myVariable matches the data stored in my other column named `TaskID`.

[image: My example]

Something like a loop that updates every single row, one after one.

```
if myVariable and TaskID matches 
    Update TaskStatus with mySecondVariable
```

I know Django has a `exist()` function so I assume that should be incoorporated into the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
Task.objects.filter(TaskID=myVariable).update(TaskStatus=mySecondVariable)
```

Please see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) for more details.

Also if you are writing this line in an external script(not associated with your project files) then make sure to run it like this:

```
python manage.py shell < your_script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a loop then it should be something like:

```
for row in TableName.objects.all():
    if myVariable == row.TaskID:
        row.TaskStatus = mySecondVariable
        row.save()
```

If you think that you don't need a loop then something like:

```
TableName.objects.filter(TaskID=myVariable).update(TaskStatus=mySecondVariable)
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct. I would also mark your answer correct if I could, but ruddra was a little bit quicker.